constexpr function that keeps multiplying a number until "it is big enough"
Ok, I completely messed up this question, first for the typo and second because my oversimplified minimum example didn't have any problem at all. I was considering to delete the question but seeing that it have two answers with fairly good acceptance I will edit with the not oversimplified code. I'm sorry for all the mess1.
The following code creates an specializaton for std::hash:
#include <bit>
#include <bitset>

struct test{ const char *const s; std::size_t n; };

template<>
struct std::hash<test>
{
    constexpr std::size_t text_hash(const char *const text) const noexcept
    {
        auto result = ~std::size_t{};
        auto shift = 0ul;
        constexpr auto length = sizeof(result) * 8;

        for (const char *c = text; *c; ++c)
        {
            result ^= (std::size_t(*c) << shift);
            shift = ((shift + 8) % length);
        }

        return result;
    }
    constexpr std::size_t expand_number(std::size_t number) const noexcept
    {
        while (std::bit_width(number) < 64)
            number *= 7ul;

        return number;
    }
    constexpr std::size_t operator()(const test &t) const noexcept
    {
        return text_hash(t.s) ^ expand_number(t.n);
    }
};

Used as follows, does not compile:
constexpr std::hash<test> HASH;
#define TEXT(T) HASH(test{T, __COUNTER__})

int main()
{
    constexpr auto v = TEXT("Test");

    return 0;
}

The error shown by the compiler (Compiler Explorer link) is:
<source>:41:24:   in 'constexpr' expansion of 'HASH.std::hash<test>::operator()(test{((const char*)"Test"), 0})'
<source>:32:46:   in 'constexpr' expansion of '((const std::hash<test>*)this)->std::hash<test>::expand_number(((std::size_t)t.test::n))'
<source>:25:9: error: 'constexpr' loop iteration count exceeds limit of 262144 (use '-fconstexpr-loop-limit=' to increase the limit)
   25 |         while (std::bit_width(number) < 64)
      |         ^~~~~

Non-constexpr version works fine:
int main()
{
    auto v = TEXT("Test");

    return 0;
}

So why is this happening? How do I solve it?

1For anyone who wants to see the previous code, which compiles without any issue, here it is.
std::size_t A(std::size_t number) noexcept // Number shouldn't be 0
{
    while (std::bit_width(number) < 64)
        number *= 7ul;

    return number;
}

constexpr std::size_t B(std::size_t number) noexcept // Number shouldn't be 0
{
    while (std::bit_width(number) < 64)
        number *= 7ul;

    return number;
}

int main()
{
    auto a = A(1);
    constexpr auto b = B(1);

    return 0;
}



@TedLyngmo I think that is just a typo in the OP.  That error message would be different if there was a missing type specifier.

After adding the type auto cannot reproduce with gcc 13.2 or clang 17.0 with C++20: demo.

@NathanOliver You are probably right. We'll need the version of gcc and possibly the compilator arguments used and maybe even which C++ standard that's being used (I'm unsure if the limits are specified / different).

Which compiler are you using?  Using GCC14 the code compiles fine when adding auto to the declaration of b: https://godbolt.org/z/P5eWTafdc

gcc 10.1 seems to be the first version with std::bit_width but it doesn't complain about the loop exceeding the limit even if I explicitly set -fconstexpr-loop-limit=262144.

Wait a second: Is sizeof(std::size_t) == 4 perhaps?

Please post a [mcve] including your compilation command and the output of gcc -v.

Ok, I completely messed up this question, first for the typo and second because my oversimplified minimum example didn't have any problem at all. I was considering to delete the question but seeing that it have two answers with fairly good acceptance I will edit with the not oversimplified code. I'm sorry for all the mess.

__COUNTER__ has an initial value of 0, so clearly your loop never terminates.
https://godbolt.org/z/jc11bd636

std::size_t is 32 (or less than 64 bit) bit in your environment so std::bit_width(number) can be at most 32 - and the condition in your loop will therefore always be true:
while (std::bit_width(number) < 64) // always true if size_t has less than 64 bit

One adaptation that will not try to make it bigger than the number of bits in std::size_t:
#include <limits>

constexpr std::size_t B(std::size_t number) noexcept
{
    while (std::bit_width(number) < std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::digits)
//                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                                      the number of bits in a size_t
        number *= 7ul;

    return number;
}


This can also be simplified to static const unsigned min_size_t = std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max / 7u;     while(number < min_size_t), though with subtly different (possibly better?) results.

Then how does the non-constexpr version ever finish?

@n.m.couldbeanAI I would guess that it gets optimized away. Looks like UB to me.

Where does "loops 25 times" come from then?

@n.m.couldbeanAI Good question. If it's compiled with a size_t that has 32 bits, the loop can't finish normally no matter how many iterations, that should be UB.

@MooingDuck That doesn't quite give the same result as you mention and I'm not sure what's it's going to be used for.

Fixed width integers are to be used in such cases. std::uint64_t is the prime candidate for code portability.

@Red.Wave Yes, it depends on what it's going to be used for. Sometimes std::size_t is "just right" - and sometimes, it's not :-) std::uint64_t may not even be available.

There are cases where the original algorithm doesn't converge. Example: auto constexpr x=1<<(numeric_limits<uint64_t>::digits-4); now the algorithm huants between x and 7*x. None of them sets the msb.

@Red.Wave I'm not exactly sure how that applies to the original algorithm. How do you use that x? (1 << 60 looks risky btw - you may want to make that uint64_t(1) << ...).

@TedLyngmo I might have missed sime details. Consider modulus algebra and evaluate 7*7 mod pow(2,4). The result is 1. Now multiply by pow(2,60); the calculations are mod pow(2,64). I don't know about the algorithm objectives. I am just giving an example of infinite loop due to specific inputs. And it can happen for any given unsigned type. My example would always be pow(2, digits-4).

If Ted Lyngmo's assertion about std::size_t being less than 64 for your implementation is correct, then clearly he's got the right answer.
But if you encounter the problem when compiling for a 64-bit target, it's possible the loop count that's exceeded is in the implementation of std::bit_width rather than the loop in B.
I peeked at an implementation of std::bit_width:

When it's not consteval, it uses intrinsic instructions.
When it is consteval it falls back to a loop to compute the result.

Perhaps there's a bug in the fallback implementation for the library you're using and it's that loop that's exceeding the maximum iterations.  Since that is used only in a constexpr context, it would match the behavior observed.
